# ¿Cómo puedo llamar código de C++ desde C? (funciones miembro)

Tags: c++, c

Esto es lo que he usado para llamar a funciones no miembro en C++ desde código de C y funciona bien.

file.cpp

```
extern  "C" void f(int);

    void f(int i){

        printf("c++!\n");
    }
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f(int);

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");

    f(1);
    return 0;
}
```

shell:

```
Hello world!
c++!
```

¿Cómo puedo llamar a funciones miembro desde C?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cuando haces código compatible entre C y C++, ese código debe poseer características comunes a ambos lenguajes. Esto implica, entre otras cosas, que el código no ha de tener clases, así como otros elementos específicos de C++.

Si necesitas que C acabe llamando a elementos propios de C++ necesitas crear una API (en C++) que encapsule toda la lógica de objetos, que no es reconocida por C, y permita su manipulación mediante el uso de funciones simples.

Un ejemplo para gestionar un string. No tengo compilador de C a mano, pero salvo algún pequeño ajuste entiendo que debería funcionar

```
// header file
#ifdef _cplusplus
#define EXTERN_C extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERN_C
#endif

typedef enum object_type
{
  ot_undefined,
  ot_string
} object_type;

typedef struct objData
{
  void* ptr;
  object_type type;
} objData;

EXTERN_C objData new_string();

EXTERN_C int set_string(objData obj, char* str);

EXTERN_C int get_length(objData obj);

EXTERN_C void delete_obj(objData* obj);

#undef EXTERN_C

// source file

objData new_string()
{
  objData toReturn;
  toReturn.ptr = new std::string;
  toReturn.type = ot_string;
  return toReturn;
}

int set_string(objData obj, char* str)
{
  int to_return = 0;

  if( obj.type == ot_string )
  {
    static_cast<std::string*>(obj.ptr)->assign(str);
    toReturn = 1;
  }

  return = toReturn;
}

int get_length(objData obj)
{
  int toReturn = -1;

  if( obj.type == ot_string )
  {
    std::string str* = static_cast<std::string*>(obj.ptr);
    toReturn = static_cast<int>(str->length());
  }

  return toReturn;
}

void delete_obj(objData* obj)
{
  bool ok = false;

  switch( obj.type )
  {
    case ot_string:
    {
      ok = true;
      std::string* str = static_cast<std::string*>(obj->ptr);
      delete str; // Si hago delete de void* no se invocan los destructores
      break;
    }
  }

  if( ok )
  {
    obj->ptr = 0;
    obj->type = ot_undefined
  }
}
```